# Prevent AutoMapper to treat string as collection in LINQ ProjectTo

Tags: c#, automapper

I've the following set of classes to map (only in one direction, from `Data*` to `Api*`):

```c#
// Top level

public class DataEntity
{
  public NestedDataEntity Nested { get; set; }
  // ... other primitive/complex properties
}

public class ApiEntity
{
  public NestedApiEntity Nested { get; set; }
  // ... other primitive/complex properties
}

// Nested level

public class NestedDataEntity
{
  public string Items { get; set; }
}

public class NestedApiEntity
{
  public IEnumerable<ApiSubItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ApiSubItem
{
  // there are properties here. Not needed for the sake of example
}
```

Mapping is configured within a `Profile` as in the following bit of code:

```c#
// mapping profile 

public class MyCustomProfile : Profile
{
  public MyCustomProfile()
  {
    CreateMap<DataEntity, ApiEntity>();
    CreateMap<NestedDataEntity, NestedApiEntity>();

    CreateMap<string, IEnumerable<ApiSubItem>>()
      .ConvertUsing<TextToSubItemsConverter>();
  }
}

// type converter definition

public class TextToSubItemsConverter :
  ITypeConverter<string, IEnumerable<ApiSubItem>>
{
  public IEnumerable<ApiSubItem> Convert(
        string dataItems, IEnumerable<ApiSubItem> apiItems, ResolutionContext context)
  {
    // actually, deserialize & return an ApiSubItem[]
    // here just return some fixed array

    return new ApiSubItem[]
    {
      new ApiSubItem(),
      new ApiSubItem(),
      new ApiSubItem(),
    };
  }
}

// Main

public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
      cfg.AddProfile<MyCustomProfile>();
    });

    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    DataEntity dataEntity = new DataEntity()
    {
      Nested = new NestedDataEntity()
      {
        Items = "Ignored text",
      },
    };

    // This maps ok, no issues
    ApiEntity apiEntity = Mapper.Map<DataEntity, ApiEntity>(dataEntity);

    IQueryable<DataEntity> dataEntities = new[] { dataEntity }.AsQueryable();

    // This exposes the System.Char to ApiSubItem issue
    ApiEntity apiEntityProjected = dataEntities.ProjectTo<ApiEntity>().First();
  }
}
```

Mapping configuration passes initial validation at startup, but then when an actual mapping is required I get exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Missing map from System.Char to my.whatever.namespace.ApiSubItem. Create using Mapper.CreateMap.

If I omit completely the configuration between `string` and `IEnumerable<ApiSubItem>`, initial validation complains about the same context:

> Context:
>     Mapping from type System.Char to my.whatever.namespace.ApiSubItem

although when added, it seems like it's not picked up by AutoMapper.

The mapping happens in a static context, through a `ProjectTo<ApiEntity>()` call on top of LINQ query over `DbSet<DataEntity>`. I've checked that converter does not require any dependency, just in case.

AutoMapper is 5.0.2, running in an MVC API web application under ASP.Net Core 1 RTM.

I've checked similar issues here on SO, but with no luck. Does anyone know how to make this type of scenario work? I guess I'm not the first one trying to (Auto)map from a `string` to a collection. TA

**EDIT** Added both failing and non-failing case to example

**EDIT 2** After further search, somewhere someone suggested to ignore the field and perform mapping in `AfterMap()`. With this profile, exception is not thrown but resulting `Items` field is null:

```
CreateMap<DataEntity, ApiEntity>();
CreateMap<NestedDataEntity, NestedApiEntity>()
    .ForMember(api => api.Items, options => options.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((data, api) =>
    {
        api.Items = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ApiSubItem>>(data.Items);
    });

CreateMap<string, IEnumerable<ApiSubItem>>()
    .ConvertUsing<TextToSubItemsConverter>();
```

**EDIT 3** Reworded question title to make it more specific for projection

Comment: you can't map string to collection in that case you need to pack items.propertyname which return type is string . becasue automapper work on one to one mapping

Comment: can you make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @PankajGupta could you please tell me again, I cannot get it.

Comment: @SamIam the core bits are there, now I edited question to add a full example. Please let me know if you think there are other parts missing

Comment: @ the downvoter, please explain motivation, so to improve question at least

Comment: @superjos  I downvoted.  The code that you've posted doesn't compile because of the `()` at the end of one of your class definitions, and once I make that change, it runs without throwing an exception.  Both of these are signs that the code you've posted isn't the code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @superjos and the problem isn't so much about the compiler errors themselves as it is with the fact that they mean you _can't_ have experienced that exception with the code you're posted.

Comment: I see. Posted code is an excerpt of course taken from larger project. It now also shows the projection case, which fails

Comment: @superjos i want to say automapper work on one to one mapping and property type also should be same so you cant map string to collection. use linq to map string property with items.propertyname

Comment: I don't think you're right on this one @PankajGupta: if you look at the example, mapping from string to collection works in non-projection case. And from examples that you can find googling around, you can check that AutoMapper can actually map between a *one* property (e.g. string) and a *many* property (e.g. a collection)

Comment: @superjos  That's why I asked you for a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  In order to make one properly, you need to make a **new** project, and make sure that it actually demonstrates your issue.  That way, I can copy and paste your code, and actually experience the issue, and verify that my solution is correct, instead of trying to guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, although I did not find your approach particularly friendly and inviting to collaboration (my taste, of course). SSCCE now should be there. In the meantime I collected more info on the topic. Please feel free to provide your answer and/or solution, if it still makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the actual answer is along the lines of "projections and converter/resolvers don't play nicely together". From AutoMapper [Queryable.Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#supported-mapping-options) wiki:

> Not all mapping options can be supported, as the expression generated must be interpreted by a LINQ provider. [...]
>
> Not supported:
>
> - [...]
> - Before/AfterMap,
> - Custom resolvers,
> - Custom type converters

**EDIT** Workaround:
In this particular scenario, I've later found to be useful having an intermediate DTO entity that could grab some more fields, not needed for the final API entity but still needed for business logic.

In such DTO entity I left the `string` field as in `DataEntity`, so I could use projection and let AutoMapper/LinqToSQL grab only needed fields from DB.

Then, between DTO entity and API entity already in memory, I could apply a second mapping which also took advantage of custom converter for `string ==> IEnumerable<ApiSubItem>` mapping. HTH